# dbgeng - load extension dlls in c++?

Tags: dll, load, windbg, dbgeng

I have written one application in which I load one system wide crash dump using dbgeng.dll. I want to use some of the WinDbg commands like (!vad) - for that I need other dll's like exts.dll, ext.dll, kext.dll, kexts.dll. I have all these dlls and have my _NT_DEBUGGER_EXTENSION_PATH properly set. When I use the WinDbg GUI - .chain command tells me that all these dlls are loaded but when I try to do it from my code - I can't see these dlls loaded. Also when I try to load these dlls using Execute (.load....) - it throws an error - " The call to LoadLibrary('...') failed, Win32 error 0n193". I tried !load as well - both of them didn't work in my code. But everything works perfectly in GUI. I am not able to figure out how to load all these dlls in my c++ code.

Could anybody please help me out here ?
I would really appreciate your help!

-arb

Answer (score 0):

Error 193 If you get error 193 usually means that you are trying to load 64-bit dll in a 32-bit application (or vice versa).

Make sure that you load dbgeng.dll from the same directory windbg is installed to.  You will then be able to use all windbg commands via `IDebugControl::Execute`

Comment: Thanks john. I am trying to enforce the dll loading from that folder but its still loading from the system folder which I don't want. If I use SetDllDirectory in my code.. that dll is still loaded from the system directory... as the dll gets loaded before setting up the dll directory - do you have any solution for this ??

Comment: Load it dynamically with LoadLibrary and use GetProcAddress to get DebugCreate.

Comment: John, I am trying to debug 32bit win7 crash dump in Windows server 2008 R2 using dbgeng.dll (which is 64 bit). I am having trouble with symbols file. Whenever I do !vad -- it could not read the VAD tree as it is not able to find the symbols, though I have copied the ntdll.pdb and ntkrpamp.pdb from the VM to the server's local directory and I am pointing to it. Do you know what could be the issue ? I would really appreciate your help. Thanks